# How create new app with personalize folder name with yeoman?

Tags: yeoman

I have tried to use yeoman with AngularJS.

When I put the command

```
yo angular
```

after the configuration it creates my app inside a folder called "app" in the path `C:\Users\USERNAME\app`

What can I do if I have to create project in a different folder maybe with a name selected by me?